# SQLiteDatabase.query() syntax in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax

This query keeps returning errors like `error near ?`.

```
public Cursor getRow2( String st, String dr) throws SQLException {
   String whereClause = "(adate ?) AND (station ?)";
   String[] whereArgs = new String[] { dr, st };
   String orderBy = "adate";

   Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, whereClause, whereArgs, 
        null, null, orderBy);
```

`String dr` is for "data-range".

- If the user does specify the two dates, then `dr` gets a value like `BETWEEN 2004-03-01 AND 2004-06-01`.
- Othewise `dr` gets `NOT NULL` so that the query finds ALL dates.

`String st` is for "gas station".

- If the user provides the station name, `st` gets a string like `'Shell'`.
- Otherwise `st` gets `NOT NULL` so as to find ALL stations.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `?` to bind only literals, not partial expressions.

`(adate ?) AND (station ?)` is not a valid expression. Binding the first arg to `BETWEEN 2004-03-01 AND 2004-06-01` and the second `Shell` makes it essentially

```
(adate 'BETWEEN 2004-03-01 AND 2004-06-01') AND (station 'Shell')
```

which is syntactically incorrect.

To use bind args with a query like this, make the query like

```
(adate BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (station = ?)
```

binding args as `"2004-03-01", "2004-06-01", "Shell"`.

For the "not specified" cases it's probably best to use different queries altogether.